# Using iOS6 Message Access Profile on App

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary, bluetooth, sms

I want to create an app to the iPad Mini that connects to iPhone using Bluetooth 4.0, and access its messages, to show on screen when I receive a E-mail, SMS or iMessage.

I think that I could use the Message Access Profile (MAP) but I didn't find a way to do that.

Can someone tell me from where I begin?

My first try was get the SMS notification using CoreTelephony, but since the iOS 5 (as I know) the message didn't came with the notification, and as my iPhone isn't jailbroken, I couldn't access the SMS.db to read it, neither using the private framework ChatKit.

I won't publish this app on appstore, it is for personal using and testing.

Comment: iPros: Are you able to start any thing on this ?

Comment: Ram, No... I discovered that for my need Bluetooth 4.0 won't work, because afaik can't be used profiles in Bluetooth 4.0. In that case I needed to buy a bluetooth chip that already comes with this profile (or upgrade its firmware to enable).

I ended using an arduino that makes the job for me!